# belongs_to with foreign_key not working in one direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, belongs-to

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product, foreign_key: :symbol
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :positions, primary_key: :symbol, foreign_key: :symbol
end
```

When I do

`Product.first.positions.first` I am getting a Product back.

But, when I do `Position.first.product` I am getting nothing.

When I look at the SQL generated by the query, it is:

`SELECT "products.*" FROM "products" WHERE "products.id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", 0]]`

Why?

Comment: Can you please show the schema/migration of these two models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL generated is using `products.id` instead of `products.symbol` because you didn't tell it that the association should use `symbol` as the primary key instead of the default of `id`. So, in your `Position` class just add `primary_key: :symbol` to the `belongs_to` and I think that'll do it.

Comment: Thanks. Out of all the things I tried, it seems like I forgot that one. So basically it means that both ends of the relation should have the foreign/primary keys set to the same attribute to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "symbol"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to revise the creation of your model `Product`.

You need to create it the following way:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, id: false do |t|
      t.string :symbol, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :products, :symbol, unique: true
  end
end
```

And then let your model know about the `primary_key`, that is not `id`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "symbol"
end
```

And after that, when you do `Product.last`, it will generate the following query:

```
Product.last
# Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  ORDER BY "products"."symbol" DESC LIMIT 1
```